# typescript function parameter type unexpected token :

Tags: typescript

Just following the simplest Typescript tutorial and when it comes to typing a function parameter I'm failing.

```
function greeter(person: string) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}

var user = "Jack";

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

But when I load the page I'm getting "Unexpected token :" - the browser is trying to parse Javascript? I get that Tyescript will compile down to JS, but I'm missing something here.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, with jQuery.d.ts to type it.

The .ts is going through TypeScriptCompile for its build action.

Body for the .aspx looks like this:

```
<div>
    <script src="Scripts/Main.ts"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: In general .ts files are compiled to .js files. Don't run just the .ts

Comment: you need a return type on your function also. since it is returning a string, you need:

    function greeter(person: string):string {
        return "Hello " + person;
    }

Comment: Return type annotations are optional; the return type of the function will be inferred from the return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to include the .ts file directly, and the browser does not understand that. In this case, it balks on the first type definition it encounters, i.e. the semicolon in

`function greeter(person: string) {`

What you need to do is compile the `Scripts/Main.ts` file to a `Scripts/Main.js` file (VS2013 should do this automatically for you), and then include that in the .aspx source code.

To verify this, there should be a `+` sign next to the `Main.ts` file in the solution explorer, and the `Main.js` file should be under that.

Comment: Thanks man. I can't see a + to let me expand my .ts, in fact there's no .js in the solution explorer at all, but it does get compiled and is in the file system so including it worked. I'd upvote if I had the rep ;)

Comment: @Jack0x539 - perhaps you could turn on the hidden files for your project? You should see the .JS file then...it's just not included in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the JS file not the TS file:

```
<div>
    <script src="Scripts/Main.js"></script>
</div>
```